# Getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined on Vue.use(Vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

In my vue frontend i tried to setup Vuex. On my store page (inside the store dir, file name index.js).Im using Vue 3.0
When i run the code i get the Cannot read property 'use' of undefined on Vue.use(Vuex) line

This is the chunk of the code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Api from "../services/api";

Vue.use(Vuex);//here i get the error

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state:{
  articles:[]
  },...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Vuex 4`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/4.0) to be Vue 3 compatible, and Vuex 4 introduced a few breaking changes, and one of them is how to initialize the store. Basically instead of using `new Vuex.Store`, you now use `createStore` to create the store object and no need to use `Vue.use(Vuex)` anymore in your `store.js`.

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

export const store = createStore({
  state: {...}
  // other stuff
})
```

And in your `main.js` file:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { store } from 'path/to/store.js';

const app = createApp({...})
app.use(store);
```

You can also see the [full Vuex 4 example on github](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/4.0#breaking-changes)

Comment: could you maybe give me a tip as to how to update to vuex 4...i changed the dependencie in package.json to vuex 4.0.0 but the console returns that this version doesnt exist

Comment: You can install it via `npm i --save vuex@next` or `npm i --save vuex@4.0.0-beta.4` which is the current beta version.